# setBgColor Codenameone not working

Tags: codenameone

i want to add a background color to my container i tried everything but it's not working i didn't know why

```
 Container c2 = new Container(BoxLayout.y());

    for (int i = 0; i < lis.size(); i++) {
        Container c1 = new Container(BoxLayout.y());

        ImageViewer iv = new ImageViewer();

        iv.setImage(Image.createImage("/" + lis.get(i).getImage()).scaledHeight(100).scaledWidth(100));
        c1.add(iv);
        c1.add(new Label(lis.get(i).getNom()));

        c1.getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(Border.createLineBorder(5));
        c1.getStyle().setBgColor(0xC40C0C);

        c2.add(c1);

    }
    f.add(c2);
```

Comment: The way codename1 containers are sized and drawn is quite complex and opaque.  Subclass Container, give it a paint(Graphics ) wrapper method, and set a breakpoint.  Check the size of the window, you might be surprised to find it's 0x0.  After calling super() draw some lines and boxes you should be able to see.   Likewise for ImageViewer.  good luck!

Comment: @ddyer i really didn't understand what u told me to do well can u please be more precise or if u can show me an example ?

Comment: I told you how I would debug the problem.  I'm afraid if you don't understand, you're not ready to do what you're doing, or you need a better teacher than me.

Answer (score 0):

Border overrides background color which can impact the background. Also you will need to set the background transparency which in container is 0 e.g.:

```
c1.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
```

I would suggest doing this in CSS or in the designer tool by defining a UIID to match your desired appearance then applying that using `c1.setUIID("MyStyledBackground");`.

You can have a border on top of the color by nesting containers.

Comment: can u please juste show me where can i set the UIID in the theme.res i've been looking for it but didn't find it and if u can please just explain me why do we set UIID like in your example c1.setUIID("MyStyledBackground") and then we will use that " MyStyledBackground" or it's juste to specify that only that container have specefics css

Comment: Did you look at the theming how do I video? https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-simple-theme.html